# UIPickerView with custom views has visual errors

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am building a custom UIPickerView where I want to show the user more information than just a line of text. In order to do that, I am building a custom view to show in the UIPickerView (which is supposed to show a Title, an image and 3 lines of text eventually).

Testing a first version, I got the whole thing running, but have some unusual visual errors. Here's what they look like (I currently only display the title, the rest is blank with a white background, the UIPickerView got a light grey background to distinguish the two):

[image: Upon first load]
When I first load the view, I can only see the grey of the UIPickerView. I adjusted the "selection window by calling `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat` and setting it to 300.

[image: Dragging the picker view]
Swiping up and down on the UIPickerView reveals that there are, in fact, the views I created for it. They can be seen disappearing in the top area of the view.

[image: After scrolling all the way down and all the way up]
Finally, after scrolling all the way down and all the way up again, I get a clear view of the first item/view. But that's it, the rest of the custom views remain hidden or are just visible in the top part when scrolling them "away".

Here is how I create the single views through a custom class (I then just append them into an array):

```
class PickerView: UIView {

    // MARK: Variables

    var titleLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    // MARK: - Init

    init(frame: CGRect, name: String) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        addTitle(name)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    // MARK: - Functions

    func addTitle(title: String) {
        // basic setup
        titleLabel.text = title
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Apple SD Gothic Neo", size: 20.0)
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()

        // position the title
        let x = (self.bounds.size.width - titleLabel.bounds.size.width) / 2
        titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, 5, titleLabel.bounds.size.width, titleLabel.bounds.size.height)
        self.addSubview(titleLabel)
    }
}
```

The array function (which creates several PickerView classes with different values and appends them into an array) is called like this: `PickerViewBuilder().getViewArrayForDimensions(filmPicker.bounds.size.width, height: pickerViewHeight)`

I'd be really glad if someone could point me in a direction (all I would be able to do now is trying out different settings/variables more or less randomly). Has it something to do with the storyboard setup or is it something in my code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can't help if you don't show any relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy Added some code.

Comment: what are in your `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` and `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:` overrides? Sorry I don't know how to write them in Swift.

Comment: @AyanSengupta the `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` simply returns `pickerViews[row]` (`pickerViews` is the array of UIViews). `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:` returns a constant: `private let pickerViewHeight: CGFloat = 300`.